# PHP - strpos with whitespace

Tags: php

I need to check if string contains specific word, but with keeping in mind that there may be whitespace in between (any kind - space, tab etc).

```
$array1 = "name @mail lastname";
$array2 = "name @ mail lastname";
$array3 = "name @        mail lastname";
$array4 = "name @ word mail lastname";

if (strpos($array1, '@mail') !== false) {
echo 'true';
}
```

So desired output would be true for array1, array2 and array3. What is the proper way to do this?

Comment: is a problem if we check if the string conatains "@" and "mail" with seperate contitions?

Comment: No, it is not a problem, as long as it gives true only for @mail (with or without whitespace) and false in case if there is some word in between or if there is no at sign and mail at all

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check that both parts are in a string:

```
if (strpos($array1, 'mail') !== false && strpos($array1, '@') !== false) {
    echo 'true';
}
```

This of course can be true for a string like `'aaaaa mail bbbb @ ccc'`.
So, you can extend:

```
$at_pos = strpos($array1, '@');
$mail_pos = strpos($array1, 'mail');
if ($at_pos !== false && $mail_pos !== false && $at_pos < $mail_pos) {
    echo 'true';
}
```

Otherwise it's time to use regexp:

```
if (preg_match('/@\s*mail/', $str)) {
    echo 'true';
}
```

Comment: That will give true in case of array4 also

Comment: Then use regexp, my last example.

Answer (score 2):

You could use this regex: `/@\s*mail/`

Code:

```
<?php

$array1 = "name @mail lastname";
$array2 = "name @ mail lastname";
$array3 = "name @        mail lastname";
$array4 = "name @ word mail lastname";

$pattern = '/@\s*mail/';

echo preg_match($pattern, $array1);
echo preg_match($pattern, $array2);
echo preg_match($pattern, $array3);
echo preg_match($pattern, $array4);
```

Which would output:

`1110`

Meaning all the inputs are matched apart from `$array4`.

Comment: Thank you. I can not accept both answers, u_mulder was first so i upwoted yours.